How do you copy files in a search to certain folders based off a portion of a filename
I have a directory full of pdf files, with names such as 1024 Billy Bloggs report.pdf
Then I have many directories in the form: 1024-Bloggs Case
I need to move all the files in the root directory into their respective directories. This involves as previously described by someone searching the files for the number, then matching to the directory name with the same identifier then moving the file.
I have tried the below in a few forms, however cannot seem to pass the wildcard to the dir command.
I have also outputed all the filename numbers to a TXT file, and have been trying to open the file, grab the number, then use it to search the filename, then the directory name and apply a move or copy command.
FOR /f "delims=" %G in (folderlist.txt) DO copy %G*.pdf %G**.*

However, this does the search of the %G*.pdf, but then the second portion doesn't work.
I tried to set the variables of the copy however isn't working, and says that "the system cannot find the file specified". It seems that even though the Source and Dest variable is saying its gathering the right dir search, it doesn't pass the same output to the Copy command.
This is the current code I'm at, any help would be great thanks.
@echo on
FOR /f "delims=" %%G in (folderlist.txt) DO (
    FOR /F "delims=" %%H IN ('dir "%%G*" /s/b/a-d') DO SET Source=%%H
    FOR /F %%I IN ('dir %%G* /s/b/ad') DO SET Dest=%%I
    copy %Source% %Dest%
    Pause
)))


Beware of the delayed expansion trap. Use set "var=value" for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Always use a setlocal flavour to avoid environment clutter. Normally, a setlocal line should follow @echo off. If you omit this line, variables set by running one batch file will remain set when the next is run in the same cmd instance, hence different results when the same script is run repeatedly.

Add the "delims=" option to the ``FOR … %%I command else the value assigned to%%Iwill be tokenised (Seefor /?) from the prompt for docco). Your copycommand could becopy "%%H" "%%I"or preferably ECHO copy "%%H" "%%I"initially to verify that the routine proposes to do whatever is required - then after verification remove theecho` keyword to arm the command.

I disagree about the parentheses. I believe that there should be a ( after each DO so that %%I is nested inside %%H is nested inside %%G

Hi Magoo, thanks for the notes on the the values, and as you mentioned the ( missing after the DO were actually what was stopping the code from executing and giving the errors. part of the fun of trying things but not 100% knowing how it correlates to the rest.

I'd do it this way (I think)
Really depends on whether the identifying factor is, eg, 1024 and that the same 1024 is unique to start the directoryname. For instance, 103 would match 103 fred directory and also 1035 george directory.
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"

FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.pdf" 2^>nul ') DO (
 REM %%e contains the source filename
 FOR /f "tokens=1" %%b IN ("%%e") DO (
  rem %%b contains prefix
  FOR /f "delims=" %%y IN ('dir "%destdir%\%%b*" /s/b/ad 2^>nul') DO (
   ECHO MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%e" "%%y\"
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF

%%e acquires all .pdf names from the source directory.
%%b then picks up the first token of the filename. The tokens=1 is actually superfluous as tokens=1 is the default, and Space is a default delimiter (see `for /? from the prompt for docco)
Then look for a directoryname in the tree that starts %%b and assign the full directoryname to %%y.
ECHO the required move command, noting that the destination includes  \ to indicate that the destination is a directory, not a file. Note the quotes to take care of file/directorynames that contain spaces.

Thanks Magoo for describing the coding and coming up with an automated working script. Mine is now working as long as i had a list of numbers, however yours matches the filename and folder perfectly. Your amazing!!!
